# Javascript: Using forms vs NOT using forms for data submission

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Nowadays it doesn't seem to matter whether you use forms or not for submitting data.  Personally, I seem to end up just getting the values from the necessary inputs, manually, using JavaScript, upon the submission of a form (or just a button that is intended to trigger a function that grabs all the input data off the page).

Are there any major differences between using forms to submit data directly over just grabbing the needed elements off a page and using AJAX to send the data?

Edit:  Would appreciate explanations if you're going to downvote.  I haven't seen the question specifically asked before on StackOverflow plus standards change pretty quickly nowadays and most new developers might wonder what the point of using a form would be over just manually grabbing inputs.

Comment: It's better to use forms for compatibility, screen readers, and for that one person who has JavaScript disabled. Plus, having the form element doesn't prevent you from using AJAX, and bots will always be able to scrape whatever input you're asking for.

Comment: You'll want to read about [progressive enhancement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement). Using HTML semantically correct only has advantages.

Comment: Nope, bots don't need forms to "exploit" your API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using forms is recommended due to the following:

1. Forms provide backwards compatibility to devices that don't look at CSS or use javascript.
2. With forms you can use tools like parsley.js to grab the wbole form, validate and send off as part of your AJAX without bothering validating every single field in your script.
3. Other developers expect to see a form because that's how HTML is meant to be, so by omitting one, you introduce unusual code, which in turn would mean wasted time by other developers when they take over your code.

**So don't reinvent the wheel and use the forms :)**

Comment: Nobody cares for other developers. But SEO and user accessibility do matter! :-)

Comment: Well, they should. "Other developers" issue can cost companies millions in waste dev time on figuring out what the heck was built there... so do care :)

Comment: Sure, and everyone *should* write extensive documentation :-) I just meant that there are other concerns that would affect your (the OPs) opinion more directly.

Comment: Ammmmm, no. Documentation should be minimal as required - your code should speak for itself. Also, I would prioritize code consistency over anything else in this thread.

Comment: While writing good and understandable (commented, if necessary) code is out of the question here, "documentation" encompasses more than just code - it describes the architecture, it explains APIs etc. I mean the stuff that costs companies millions and wastes dev time when it's missing :-)

Comment: @Bergi I do care about other developers, which is why I asked the question.  I always try to create well documented and maintainable code.  That's just common knowledge among good developers (unless you're purposely making your code obscure for job security reasons, which isn't unheard of).  Appreciate the feedback, Alexus!

Comment: "unless you're purposely making your code obscure for job security reasons" - if this is the case, the person doing it is lacking skills to outperform others on a different scale. Cheers! :)

Comment: @Bergi Exactly. And to make sure documentation is still readable, add whatever is not conventional or can't be described by code there, but leave out as much as possible by writing conventional code that conforms to standards.